# Override a logic which is written in OnPreRender on a Page

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pageload, prerender

I have a logic where I disable a link using `OnPreRender` Method in all pages. But on one specific page I want to enable this link **if a specific condition is satisfied**, such as if the link text is 'India.'

I tried to do this on `Page_Load` of that page but it gets overridden by the `OnPreRender` method.

Is there any way to achieve this without disturbing the existing `OnPreRender` method?

Comment: Why not put the logic you have in `OnPreRender` in `PageLoad` and then add your specific condition to `OnPreRender`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the control lifecycle in ASP .NET:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(v=vs.71).aspx

`Page_Load` occurs before `OnPreRender`.  You might be able to override the `OnRender` event since that occurs after `OnPreRender`.

This is how you can override the Render method in a ASP.NET page:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  // Do stuff here, make the link enabled/disabled etc.
  // Be sure to call base.Render() as well if appropriate.
}
```

Comment: How can I use it to disable a link? I am not aware of the OnRender Event and how to use it for my purpose. Can you shed some light on this?